# ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'str'>

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two dfs: df_main_lat_lon and df_lat_lat_lon. They are as follows:
[image]

[image]

When I merged these two dfs as:

merged_inner = pd.merge('df_tp_lat_lon', 'df_main_lat_lon', on=['LATITUDE', 'LONGITUDE'], how='inner')

I received following error:
ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type

Anyone can help me to solve this issue? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
merged_inner = pd.merge(df_tp_lat_lon, df_main_lat_lon, on=['LATITUDE', 'LONGITUDE'], how='inner')
```

DataFrame names should not be indicated as a string.